# Stopping a function inside a namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I have a namespace with a method to stop some characters being entered on a keypress event for inputs. If the character is detected, it returns false but I think that because it's called when the keypress is fired, the character still gets entered. How do I fix this problem?

If I take the function out of the namespace it works as intended but I don't want that.

HTML

```
<div id="personal-info">
    <input id="first-name" class="personal-info" autofocus/><p id="error-first-name" class="error-text"></p>
    <input id="last-name" class="personal-info"/><p id="error-last-name" class="error-text"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    fsa = (function() {

        //OK - get selected element ID and write ID
        var inputId = "";
        var sigId = "";
        var errId = "";
        function GetAndSetLoc() {
            inputId = document.activeElement.id;
            sigId = "sig-" + document.activeElement.id;
            errId = "error-" + document.activeElement.id;
        }
        var thisId = "";

        // on button down, if the character is illegal, change the css of the error box
        function showError(keyCode) {
        var keys = [13,
        "<".charCodeAt(0),
        ">".charCodeAt(0),
        "$".charCodeAt(0),
        "(".charCodeAt(0),
        ")".charCodeAt(0),
        "?".charCodeAt(0),
        "{".charCodeAt(0),
        "}".charCodeAt(0),
        "/".charCodeAt(0),
        "#".charCodeAt(0),
        "&".charCodeAt(0),
        "*".charCodeAt(0),
        "@".charCodeAt(0),
        "~".charCodeAt(0)
        ];

            var index;
            for (index = 0; index < keys.length; ++index) {

                if (keys[index] === keyCode) {
                    errorObject = $('#' + errId);
                    errorObject.html("Sorry, invalid character.").addClass('error');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        errorObject.html("Sorry, invalid character.").removeClass('error');
                    }, 2000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            GetAndSetLoc: GetAndSetLoc,
            showError: showError
        }

    })();

    // --------- Call the functions

    //OK - get current read and write ids
    $('.personal-info').focus(function(){
        fsa.GetAndSetLoc();
    });

    $("input").keypress(function(e) {
        fsa.showError(e.keyCode);
    });
```

Comment: Try using keydown event instead

Answer (score 0):

return **false** from keypress event in case of error

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
       return fsa.showError(e.keyCode);
    });
```